# The disk tray won't open when I press the button

Tags: 12.10, mount, lubuntu, disk

I'm trying to open the disk tray in Lubuntu 12.10 and nothing is happening. This can't be a mechanical failure because it works fine in Windows XP, and I'm posting it here because there are no packages I know of related to disk trays at all. I can also open the tray when I'm in the BIOS, so I must be missing a driver.

Comment: With "disk tray", are you referring to an optical disc drive tray? If so, what does `sudo eject -i off && sudo eject` do? And no, there are no drivers for optical drives.

Comment: @gertvdijk Yes. The command you asked me to try does open the optical drive. I guess I could make that button run that command.

Comment: Some application on your machine might lock it and that's why the `sudo eject -i off` works - this forces an unlock command. Try to find out what application causes this: CD burning applications, media players, etc.

Comment: The only applications that I can see blocking it are Xfburn, Gnome MPlayer, and Audacious. I killed all running instances while they were running, and tried hitting the button again, still no result.

Comment: Killing an application *after* it has sent this "lock" command will keep it locked and just cause this issue. Gracefully closing such an application *should* release this lock. It's hard to tell which application causes this from here.

Comment: Do you have any idea where the lock file would be? Unlocking it should solve the problem...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7372/discussion-between-gertvdijk-and-user1610406)